# How do you establish context and call an WebSphere EJB from the Sun JRE (not IBM)

Tags: websphere, ejb, java

Is there a way to call an EJB that is served through WebSphere (iiop://host:port/ejbName) from a vanilla JRE (like Sun). A lot of people have been telling me that this type of architecture relies in a homogenous environment. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it’s possible, I wouldn’t recommend it because you’re asking for troubles using RMI-IIOP in a heterogeneous environment.

My approach would be to expose the EJB as a web service and consume at the client.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.  You have to create something called a thin client.  It has limitations on JNDI lookups due to not being part of the container environment, so fully qualified names have to be used.

Just search for "thin client ibm ejb" on google.  Unfortunately, I don't have the link to the appropriate libraries (for WAS 6) here, they are at work.

Comment: Robin Iwould love to accept and vote up your answer but if you could provide some source code samples it would be perfect.